# how to make text Moving Persian in basic4android[b4a]

Tags: persian, basic4android

Im have a problem in basic 4 andriod

how to make a text in basic 4 android that moving from left to right and write a moving text???

im need help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text is in a label, either call the below code in a for loop or a timer:

```
label.left=label.left-5 'This moves our label 5 pixels to the left.
```

The same can be done for any control.

Answer (score 0):

as "mikeward2534" said above you should increase or decrease **left** property of view such as label and etc.but if you want it infinite moving you should write a condition in Timer that if label is out of phone border start from left or right again.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use [TextView].SetLayoutAnimated if you want to move a TextView with animation.
hopefully it would help you